# Why does my zip function put out more than the shortest iterable?

Tags: python-3.x, list, closures, generator

I have trouble understanding the output of following code.

```
def gengen(mp):
    def gen(start):
        while True:
            if start % mp == 0:
                yield start
            start += 1
    return gen

threes = gengen(3)
fours = gengen(4)

for d, v, i in zip(threes(10), fours(17), range(2)):
    print (d, v)

#output: 12 20 (this one is clear to me since 12/20 are the next integer divisible by 3/4)
         15 24 (this one is not!)
```

Why does it print out *15 24* as well? It is my understanding that the number of elements `zip` function puts out will be equal to the shortest iterable.
So I thought that `print(list(zip(threes(10), fours(17), range(2))` prints out **[12,20,0]**
Why does it call the `gengen` function again until it reaches the higher bound of `range(x)`?

I hope my question is somewhat understandable, but to make it shorter: What is the reason that 15 24 is printed out as well?

Comment: The shortest iterable in your `zip()` is `range(2)` (that's two elements - so you will get two iterations). You are printing `d` and `v` variable (not `i`), so that's why you see `12 20` (first iteration) and `15 24` (second iteration)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `zip` will look for the shortest of the passed iterables. In your case `range(2)` is the shortest iterable of the three (the other two iterables will yield infinitely), so that will result in 2 cycles of the loop.

Maybe easier to grasp by visualizing it:

```
print(list(zip(threes(10), fours(17), range(2))))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [(12, 20, 0), (15, 24, 1)]
> ```